# ssh, fail2ban and max login attempts

Tags: ssh, fail2ban, ubuntu-18.04

I am testing `fail2ban` in a `Ubuntu 18.04 LTS server` in `VirtualBox`. 
I set `maxretry = 3` in `/etc/fail2ban/jail.local`, and I tried to ssh connect from another virtual machine with a wrong password. After 3 attempts I received the following output:

```
$ asarluhi@10.20.14.200: Permission denied (publickey, password).
```

On the server side, I checked fail2ban status:

```
$ fail2ban-client status sshd
|- Filter
|  |- Currently failed: 1
   |- Total failed: 2
   | File list: /var/log/auth.log
 - Actions
   |- Currently banned: 0
   |- Total banned: 0
    - Banned IP list:
```

As you can see, `fail2ban` counted 2 failures instead of three and did not ban any machine, while I expected it to ban the machine from which I ssh connected to the server. Consequently, I did not receive any email alert from `fail2ban`. 
 If it was not `fail2ban` to close the shh connection at the third attempt, I wonder if something else (ssh?) did close it before it could be logged by fail2ban.

Answer (score 1):

Your sshd configuration may be more restrictive. Fail2ban would block connections from your IP completely, so you would get a connection timeout.

"Permission denied" shows that you are still able to connect to sshd, so that is most likely where the message comes from.

Check your MaxAuthTries value in your sshd config, and set it at least 1 higher than fail2ban (or set fail2ban to be more restrictive)